# Conditional check between tuples

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check between tuples values but failed with error as: *Binary operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type (@value String!, @value String!) and (String!, String!)*

Is it possible to do binary checks between two tuples?

```
var guest: (String!, String!)
{
    return ("guest", "1234")
}

if (txtEmail.text, txtID.text) == guest // << returning error here
{
    println("Welcome guest user!")       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift there is currently no built-in `==` for tuples. You can do this instead:

```
if txtEmail.text == guest.0 && txtID.text == guest.1 {
    // ...
```

Or, you can define your own `==` for them:

```
func ==<A: Equatable, B: Equatable>(lhs: (A, B), rhs: (A, B)) -> Bool {
    return lhs.0 == rhs.0 && lhs.1 == rhs.1
}
```

In your case, though, I would use a struct:

```
struct User: Equatable {
    let email: String
    let id: String
}
func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.email == rhs.email && lhs.id == rhs.id
}

let guest = User(email: "guest@example.com", id: "1234")
// ...
```

Comment: Make sure you copied the struct and the `==` definition.